# 'Unable to cast object of type PhysicalFileProvider to type CompositeFileProvider' when publish blazor server app to iis on windows 11

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, blazor

I'm facing this error in event viewer when publish my blazor server app to iis in windows 11 :

> System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider' to type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.CompositeFileProvider'

And in my browser facing this error :

> HTTP Error 500.30 - ASP.NET Core app failed to start.

It works in my visual studio, but i don't know what is the problem in published version!!

The detail info in event viewer is :

> Application: w3wp.exe CoreCLR Version: 7.0.523.17405 .NET Version:
> 7.0.5 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast
> object of type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider' to type
> 'Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.CompositeFileProvider'.    at
> SmartMIS.Shared.Extensions.ConfigureStaticModuleFiles(WebApplication
> app) in
> E:\Development\Projects\Backups\SmartMIS\14020509.3\SmartMIS\SmartMIS.Shared\Extensions.cs:line
> 32    at Program.$(String[] args) in
> E:\Development\Projects\Backups\SmartMIS\14020509.3\SmartMIS\SmartMIS.Web\Program.cs:line
> 37

And here is my code which cause the problem :

```
public static WebApplication ConfigureStaticModuleFiles(this WebApplication app)
        {
            var moduleManagerService = app.Services.GetService<ModuleManager>();
            var originalFileProviders = ((CompositeFileProvider)app.Environment.WebRootFileProvider).FileProviders.ToList();
            StaticAssetInfo staticAssetInfo = new StaticAssetInfo();
            foreach (IModulePackage modulePackage in moduleManagerService.Packages)
            {
                Assembly assembly = modulePackage.GetType().Assembly;
                var newPathProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(assembly, "wwwroot");
                originalFileProviders.Add(newPathProvider);
            }

            app.Environment.WebRootFileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(originalFileProviders.ToArray());

            return app;
        }
```

Any help would be great appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, apparently `app.Environment.WebRootFileProvider` is not a `CompositeFileProvider`. Why do you expect it to be one?

Comment: Thanks for reply, i've load razor class libraraies dynamically, and use this code to add it's static files to my main project.

Comment: This code works in my visual studio, but i don't know why not works when i publish to iis!!

Comment: Check whether the attribute value of hostingModel in the configuration file is OutOfProcess. If the value of the hostingModel property is InProcess, try to change it to OutOfProcess and start the project again.

Comment: I've changed hostingModel, but still facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I've changed my static method as follow and works :

```
public static WebApplication ConfigureStaticModuleFiles(this WebApplication app)
        {
            var moduleManagerService = app.Services.GetService<ModuleManager>();
            List<IFileProvider> originalFileProviders = new List<IFileProvider> { app.Environment.WebRootFileProvider };
            StaticAssetInfo staticAssetInfo = new StaticAssetInfo();
            foreach (IModulePackage modulePackage in moduleManagerService.Packages)
            {
                Assembly assembly = modulePackage.GetType().Assembly;
                var newPathProvider = new ManifestEmbeddedFileProvider(assembly, "wwwroot");
                originalFileProviders.Add(newPathProvider);
            }

            app.Environment.WebRootFileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(originalFileProviders.ToArray());

            return app;
        }
```

As you see, i've used list of 'IFileProvider' instead of compositeFileProvider.
regards ..